# Send my converted base64 output from Python ,to the Arduino?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, pyserial

I am a beginner in programming. I write a code to convert images into base64. I attached that python script bellow. Then I need to send that output data of base64 to my Arduino board. But it shows some problems and nothing going happen on the Arduino. Please help me to solve this problem.

**python script**

```
import base64
import serial
with open ("image.png","rb") as img_file:





my_string= base64.b64encode(img_file.read())
#print(my_string)
encoded=my_string.decode('utf-8')
print(encoded)
Arduino_Serial=serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
Arduino_Serial.write(my_string)
Arduino_Serial.close()
```

**Arduino script**

```
String myText;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LEDTrans, OUTPUT);
while(Serial.available())
{
myText=Serial.readString();
}
```

Please guide me to do this.I need to send image converted base64 ouput to the ardiono.I need to serial read that base64 ouput to the "myText".
please help me solve this anyone..

Comment: this looks right

Comment: you can send it to Arduino. not to IDE

Comment: Arduino resets on new USB connection and stays 2 seconds in the bootloader

Comment: i didnt get that!!sorry..is that code error??